# ReactJS: How to keep state of child without using the parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a school project using ReactJS and I'm making a simple character-creator for tabletop.
Essentially it's a wizard who guides you through the various steps of your character creation.

Each of the steps is it's own component and it contains input-fields provided by a separate Utils-file.

My main component has a render like this:

```
<div className="content-wrapper">
     {this.state.stage === 0 &&
         <PlayerInfo/>
     }
     {this.state.stage === 1 &&
         <h1>General Information</h1> //(Temp) Include from general_information.js-File instead here
     }
     {this.state.stage === 2 &&
         <h1>Race Selection</h1> //(Temp) Include from race.js-File instead here
     }
(...)
</div>
```

We then have the "PlayerInfo"-component in a separate class which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { InputField } from "./Utils";

export class PlayerInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "Max Mustermann",
            charID: "",
        };
        this.submitNameHandler = this.submitNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.submitIDHandler = this.submitIDHandler.bind(this);
    }

    submitNameHandler(value) {
        this.setState({name: value});
        console.log("This is from the parent: " + value);
    }

    submitIDHandler(value) {
        this.setState({charID: value});
        console.log("This is from the parent: " + value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Test
                <InputField value={this.state.name} handler={this.submitNameHandler}/>

                ID-Input
                <InputField value={this.state.charID} handler={this.submitIDHandler}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and finally a "Utils"-File with the input component:

```
import React from 'react';

export class InputField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isSubmitted: false,
            value: this.props.value,
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({isSubmitted: true,});
        var valueVariable = this.inputValue.value
        this.setState({value:valueVariable});
        this.props.handler(valueVariable)
        console.log(valueVariable)
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    <input className={this.state.isSubmitted ? 'submitted' : ''} ref={(c) => this.inputValue = c} type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </label>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

My problem is as follows:
When I switch from "Player Info" to "General Information" and the next steps, naturally the new component is rendered and the old one is discarded. Which then of course means I loose the input-values I have entered previously so I have to type them in again when I go back. Now I know I could prevent that by adding values to the state of my main component and passing methods down to change that state (as I did for the input-component and PlayerInfo). However that would mean I would end up with dozens of values and methods for all the following inputs (and there are a lot) and I would prefer to have my main component as clean as possible.

Is there a way to store the values in the "PlayerInfo"-component without loosing them when rendering a different component?

Answer (score 0):

In your Parent component make state of fields of all your child components
With your input handler assign the values
and pass the parent state to the child component as props
.In child component check if props are not empty then assign the value
This way even when component is removed, when it is rendered again it will have those values.